# sqldf blank join generates unexpected results

Tags: r, sqldf

I have df1  and df2 and sql join  :

```
df1 <- data.frame(fn1 = c('','NA','' ,'BF'),
              ln1 = c('DRFA', 'DEFF','DDFF', 'ANCD'))
 df2 <- data.frame(fn2 = c('','AA','BB', 'BF'),
              ln2 = c('DRFA', 'DEFF','FFFF', 'ANCD'))

library(sqldf)

nm = sqldf("
select a.*, b.*,
  (a.fn1 !=' '  and a.fn1 == b.fn2  ) as fnm,
  (a.ln1 == b.ln2) as lnm
  from df1 a, df2 b
  where (fnm + lnm)>= 1

       ")
 > nm
   fn1  ln1 fn2  ln2  fnm lnm
1       DRFA     DRFA   1   1
2  NA   DEFF  AA DEFF   0   1
3       DDFF     DRFA   1   0
4  BF   ANCD  BF ANCD   1   1
```

The results should be that fnm in 1 and 3 should be 0.  How to correct it?
Thanks

Comment: you checked `a.fn1 != ' '` which results to T for 1 and 3 because the value is `''` not `' '`. try `a.fn1 != ""` ?

Comment: it will generate error:Error: unexpected string constant in:
"    
           ""

Comment: because you have `sqldf("` you must use `'` inside

Comment: You have to use `a.fn1!=''`, not `a.fn1~=""`. That works for me. Row 3 is now missing because fnm and lnm are both 0.

Comment: @JamesTobin you should post this as an answer.

Comment: wasn't sure if that little thing was what OP was asking about, guess it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you checked `a.fn1 != ' '` which results to `T` for 1 and 3 because the value is `''` not `' '`. try `a.fn1 != ''`

Comment: Thanks. it works.   I transferred the codes from SAS in which they worked

Comment: So R distinguished '' and '   '. How can we know the blank is generated by '' and '  '. Thanks.